# The value of an infinite product containing the zeta function of Riemann.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the value of $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta\left(2^k\right)$
where $\zeta{(z)}$ is the Riemann $\zeta$ function?

This problem arose out of an attempt to compute several sums involving $\zeta{(z)}$.

I have tried using formulas such as
$\displaystyle \zeta{(2n)}=\frac{2^{2n-1}\pi^{2n}|B_{2n}|}{(2n)!}$ but without avail. Interestingly the product converges with great rapidity.

If I could find an expression for the function $\phi{(a)}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(1-a^{2^k})}}$ I could solve the problem. This I was unable to do.

Note, however, the product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(1+a^{2^k})}}$ is known.

Frustrating.

Comment: I think your question is a beautiful one, but if you wish to receive more attention and a reopening of it, you should share with the community your solution efforts.

Comment: Some motivation for the problem and a description of my approaches is included.  Thank you.

Comment: Would [this other product representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/08/0002/) help?

Comment: With respect to $\phi(a)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-a^{2^k}}$, since $\phi(a)$ has poles at $a=\pm 1$ and I believe $\phi(a)$ evaluates to $0$ for $|a|>1$, I assume you're interested evaluating $\phi(a)$ in the range $-1<a<1$? Is there a specific value of $a$ related to your problem?